# Send output from rake to email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, mailnotifier

Rails 3.1.1 and Heroku

I am running a few Rake-commands every night on my app that is hosted at Heroku. The rake commands produces some `puts` rows that I would like to read in the morning to see how the updates performed by rake was performed.

Preferably, I would like this info emailed to me and this seems like it should not be too difficult, but what do I need to do?

The rake_notifier gem does not seem to be the solution, since I want the output even when the rake is successful (rake_notifier seems to only send info when the rake crashes).

Update: I do not know ruby well enough so I have probably missed out on very simple solutions. The problems is just as much to "gather" that data. Emailing it to me is the next step in the problem chain. Right now I am only checking my logs and they are flooded with tons of other data.

Comment: And you can't pipe the output from the command line to the mail program? Sorry, I don't know Heroku.

Comment: I probably can, I have quite a few holes in my Rails-programming skills so this is probably an easy solution.

Comment: In that case you will probably want to do something like <command> | mail -s "Subject" <email address>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in rake task file do the following:

log_string = ""

begin

    # type all your code here

    # instead of using puts use

 
    log_string += "print log whatever you want" + "\n\n"

rescue

   # rescue ur code

end

# mail your log_string through a mailer that you are using.

Hence, either your rake task is successful or not, you will get your log in your mail.

Even you can mail yourself, the error message created in rake task, and that you can define in rescue block.

Comment: Sorry, it took some time before I could test it.